# Trying to create a flexible 3 button footer

Tags: css

Here is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/8BJ94/68/

I need the buttons to be positioned centrally with a bit of padding around each one in the footer.

I've very close but the buttons seems to be overflowing off the bottom of the page?

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
}

div#footer{
    width:100%;
    height:10%;
    bottom:0;
    top:90%;
    left:0;
    background-color:#2A2A2A;
    position:fixed;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}


#button {
    height : 90%;
    width : 30%;
    background-color : #FFFFFF;
    margin:1.666%;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
    -moz-border-radius: 1em;
    border-radius: 1em;
}
#button:before {
    content:'';
    height:10%;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
}

<div id="footer">
    <div id="button">button text</div>
    <div id="button">button text</div>
    <div id="button">button text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't have elements sharing the same ID. You should change those button IDs to a class instead. IDs are meant to be unique.

Comment: Ooops. School boy error

Comment: do the buttons need to be center both horizontal and vertical or just horizontal?

Comment: both please. A bit like this http://jsfiddle.net/8BJ94/72/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed a lot of your css, this is what I have now:

http://jsfiddle.net/wf_4/8BJ94/78/

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
}
html {
    display:table;
}
body {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background:#48a;
    text-align:center;
}
div#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:10%;
    min-height:40px;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background-color:#2A2A2A;
    position:fixed;
    padding:8px;
    display:table;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.button {
    height : 50%;
    width : 30%;
    background-color : #FFFFFF;
    margin:auto 2%;
    display:table-cell;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
    -moz-border-radius: 1em;
    border-radius: 1em;
}
.button:before {
    content:'';
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
}
.buttonGap {
     height:50%;
     width:1%;
     display:inline-block;
 }
```

and HTML:

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="button">button text</div>
    <div class="buttonGap"></div>
    <div class="button">button text</div>
    <div class="buttonGap"></div>
    <div class="button">button text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looking good! Any chance of having a small gap around the buttons so they are not touching?

Comment: Yes, I'll take a look at that, because they are using `display:table-cell` you may need to insert something between them with a small width as `margin` will not work... Give me 5 mins.

Comment: @totalitarian I have edited my answer and changed the fiddle link to show the new css. Now, its not very semantic but it works.

Comment: You could also add more spaces at the start and end if you wanted to have the buttons appear more central and not take the entire width.

Comment: Thanks, but now the button text isn't vertically aligned in the button

Comment: Oops. Fixed that now @totalitarian it was fine in IE, I never checked any other browsers. Works ok now.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you need:
http://jsfiddle.net/e2262/1/

What was frorcing your footer to don't be elastic vertical (in height was)

```
div#footer {
  height:10%;
  top:90%;
}
```

SO i get ride of those 2 attribute in the CSS. Now it's anchored to the bottom and as the buttons grow the footer is able to grow in height ;)

**Note**: never use multiple elements with the CSS id attribute. I swapped with CSS classes

Comment: The footer doesn't change height for when I resize the page now. It needs to remain at 10% of page height

Answer (score 0):

Just set the height of the button class to smaller, like this (note: I changed the button id's into classes, as id's should be unique - also pointed out by one of the commenters):

```
.button {
    height : 60%; // <-- changed this
    width : 30%;
    background-color : #FFFFFF;
    margin:1.666%;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
    -moz-border-radius: 1em;
    border-radius: 1em;
}
```

**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/8BJ94/75/)**

Comment: Doesn't work for me as the button is no longer centered vertically

Comment: you mean the button text? because the button itself looks like centered vertically in my fiddle...

Comment: drag the result window smaller and you'll see.

Answer (score -1):

I've updated my solution using `flex-box`:

HTML:

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="button">button text</div>
    <div class="button">button text</div>
    <div class="button">button text</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    div#footer{
        position:fixed; 
        height: 10%;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        background-color:#2A2A2A;     
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        text-align:center;  
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: center;
    }

    #footer .button {
        display: inline-block;
        background-color : #FFFFFF;            
        -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
        -moz-border-radius: 1em;
        border-radius: 1em;
        width: 30%;
        height: 80%;
        line-height: 25px;
    }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmhLU/1/)

Comment: Thanks but footer doesn't resize with the window